# Give an ETA on a file transfer

Tags: linux, bash, debian

On Debian Squeeze, I have a file that is being copied from `.` to `./copy`. If I run `watch du` I can see the size of both directories change over time. How can I parse output from `du` so that I can see a percentage and eta for the file copy? Note that in this case, the copy will be completed when `./copy` is half the size of `.`, since `.` contains `./copy`.

Comment: what if some other process is messing around in the same directory?

Comment: @MarcB It shouldn't be, as this directory is not in a location where other processes will use it, though I hadn't considered the possibility, which is a good point to consider.

Comment: If you use `dd` to copy the file, then you can monitor progress by sending a `USR1` signal to the `dd` process.

Comment: @svetianov The file copy was started through a web interface and has already been running for a while. I'm not sure which process is doing the actual copy. Thanks for this tip- though; it'll save me the hassle of installing dcfldd in the future.

Comment: Would running something like `du -sb ./copy | awk '{print $1}'` for each directory help?

Comment: @svetianov That's exactly the piece I needed, the rest is just math. Thank you!

Comment: I got `echo "scale=2;200*\`du -sb ./copy | awk '{print $1}'\`/\`du -sb . | awk '{print $1}'\`" | bc`. I can't put it through `watch` without a ton of escaping, but oh well. It works; it outputs the total percentage of the current copy operation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pv: `pv testfile > copy/testfile`, or rsync: `rsync --progress testfile copy/`.